# How to access lists of a sub-site in Sharepoint using web services?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, powershell

I'm experiencing problems when trying to access my sharepoint site using web services (on powershell) given the following configuration:

- my site is located at `https://sharepoint.company.tld/sites/siteid/`
- the WSDL was fetched from `https://sharepoint.company.tld/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` (redirected from `https://sharepoint.company.tld/sites/siteid/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`)

After building the web service DLL (following [these](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/zach/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9) steps), I do a

```
$list = New-Object Lists
```

and try to obtain a list by it's GUID (known to me):

```
$docs = $list.GetList("GUID-HERE")
```

This results in an exception:
[image: screenshot]
Retrieving the list by it's name is the same.

Doing a `$list.GetListCollection()` returns me the lists known by `https://sharepoint.company.tld` and yes, my list is not amongst these. Only some lists containing webparts that shall be used for the real sites and similar stuff.

**So, here's the question:** Is there any way how I could tell the web services that they shall not access a list located under `https://sharepoint.company.tld` but to search my lists located at `https://sharepoint.company.tld/sites/siteid/Lists`?

Comment: If you paste full code, I can tell you exactly where you have to make the change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this:
http://www.nivot.org/2008/02/29/ManipulatingRemoteSharePointListsWithPowerShell.aspx

You just need to set up Url property

```
$list.Url = "http://sharepoint/sites/root/subsite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
```