# How do I upload a file from the local machine to Sharepoint using Perl SOAP::Lite?

Tags: perl, sharepoint, soap, soaplite

```
#use SOAP::Lite ( +trace => all, maptype => {} );
use SOAP::Lite maptype => {};
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

#credentials' file
require "c:\\test\\pass.pl";
my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1);

sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
    return $username => $password;
}
my $soap
  = SOAP::Lite
  ->uri('<mysite>/_vti_bin/lists.asmx')
  ->on_action(sub {join '/', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItemsLocal', $_[1]})
  ->proxy('<mysite>/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx?BaseType=0', keep_alive => 1);

# my $method = SOAP::Data->name('CopyIntoItemsLocal')
# ->attr({xmlns => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'});
# my @params =  (SOAP::Data->name(SourceUrl => $source),
# SOAP::Data->name(DestinationUrl => $destination) );
# print $soap->call($method => @params)->result;

my $fileName = 'c:\test\abc.txt';
my $destDir  = "<mysite>/Lists/sharepoint1/";

#load and encode Data
my $data;
open(FILE, $fileName) or die "$!";

#read in chunks of 57 bytes to ensure no padding in the middle (Padding means extra    space for large files)
while (read(FILE, $buf, 60 * 57)) {
    $data .= encode_base64($buf);
}
close(FILE);

#make the call
print "uploading $fileName...";
$lists = $soap->GetList();
my $method = SOAP::Data->name('CopyIntoItemsLocal')->attr({xmlns => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'});
my @params = (
    SOAP::Data->name('SourceUrl')->value($fileName)->type(''),
    SOAP::Data->name('DestinationUrls')->type('')->value(
        \SOAP::Data->name('string')->type('')->value($destDir . $fileName)
    ),
    SOAP::Data->name('Fields')->type('')->value(
        \SOAP::Data->name('FieldInformation')->type('')->attr({Type => 'File'})->value('')
    ),
    SOAP::Data->name('Stream')->value("$data")->type('')

);

#print Results
print $soap->call($method => @params)->result;

#print $response->headerof('//CopyResult')->attr->{ErrorCode};
```

```
#use SOAP::Lite ( +trace => all, maptype => {} );
use SOAP::Lite maptype => {}; 
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64);
require "c:\\test\\pass.pl";
my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive=>1);
#setup connection
sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials { 
 return $username => $password;
}
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
       -> uri('http://<mysite>')
       -> on_action( sub{ join '/', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap',  $_[1] })
       -> proxy('http://<mysite>/_vti_bin/lists.asmx',keep_alive => 1);

$lists = $soap->GetListCollection();
quit(1, $lists->faultstring()) if defined $lists->fault();
my @result = $lists->dataof('//GetListCollectionResult/Lists/List');
foreach my $data (@result) {
    my $attr = $data->attr;
    foreach my $a qw'Title Description DefaultViewUrl Name ID WebId ItemCount' {
        printf "%-16s %s\n", $a, $attr->{$a};
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

The authentication seems to be working. First I thought that the `GetlistCollection` Web service is working, as when I made call using that Web service, it returned a page. But I think the call is returning the page I specified in the `proxy` argument.

I am able to get the collection of list on the particular site on the sharepoint.

I have used GetListCollection. However I did not really understand the code which is printing the list. I just copied it from [squish.net](http://www.squish.net/log/2008/10/11/perl-sharepoint/). Now I am trying to use the `CopyIntoItemsLocal` web service.

We have a repository of files on one server (SVN) and I have to write a Perl script which when executed will copy the files and directories from SVN to sharepoint along with the directory structure.

I will appreciate any help or tips. Since it is a big task, I am doing it in modules.

Comment: Help us help you. Expand on your question here. You've provided some code, but tell us what you expect to happen, and what is happening.

Comment: I've tried it myself but had no luck (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277340/accessing-a-sharepoint-using-perl-and-webdav). I ended up using PowerShell called from Perl (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657954/how-to-access-lists-of-a-sub-site-in-sharepoint-using-web-services, http://www.nivot.org/nivot2/post/2008/02/29/ManipulatingRemoteSharePointListsWithPowerShell.aspx)

Comment: I have included the code below the previous code. Sorry about that. I could not figure out how to include new code in separate section.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using [soapUI](http://soapui.org) (formerly by eviware, now by smartbear) an open source soapUI testing tool.  This will allow you to send soap transactions back and forth without any other user interface.  Once you are sure your transactions work and you can parse the data to get what you want, then I would make the move to use Perl to automate those transactions.

This helps you eliminate errors in your requests early on, figure out how to parse responses, and familiarize yourself with the API.